# PHP: mysql_connect(): [2002] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomput (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)

Tags: php, mysql, debian

i try to connect to the mysql server on localhost via a php script:

```
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysecret');
```

but i get always the message:

> mysql_connect(): [2002] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomput (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)

I think the translation of this german message is:

> mysql_connect(): 2002 No such file or directory (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)

I can use phpMyAdmin with that credentials - so they are correct and the mysql server is running generally. When running the MySql client from console i do not have a problem:

> mysql -u root -p
>
> Enter password:
>
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>
> Your MySQL connection id is 86
>
> Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5 (Debian)
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
>
> mysql> quit
>
> Bye

A connect to localhost at the default port (3306) via telnet works but i lost the connection each time:

> telnet localhost 3306 Trying
>
> 127.0.0.1...
>
> Connected to localhost.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.
>
> ?
>
> 5.0.51a-24+lenny5`w'V\MJmg,<42;rMkQ3IW[Connectionclosed by foreign host.

As the manual explains to me, i think it is the fallback to a socket if 'localhost' is used. I can not find a mysql.sock in my debian lenny - so i can not point the mysql.default_socket to that path.

Maybe i am not on the correct path - would be nice if you can pinpoint me the solution.

Comment: I don't speak german but I think it means "Could not establish conection to target computer" or something like that. Have you tried to use empty string `""` instead of password, because it's default on localhost? It's just blind guess.

Comment: The translation is something like "Could not establish conection, because the targetcomp..." and there the message is cut. However, try a modern mysql-extension (mysqli, ..)

Comment: Can you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: @Wrikken, unless the host's `hosts` file is totally mangled, 'localhost' is always 127.0.0.1 (ipv4) or ::1 (ipv6)

Comment: Yes, and with these kinds of problems, usually, either the `localhost` reference is kaput, and `localhost` defaults to socket for the mysql client app, while `127.0.0.1` doesn't. I didn't ask for nothing :)

Comment: @Wrikken - you're right, sometimes it works only with 127.0.0.1 (from my experience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find mysql.sock with:

```
$ locate mysql.sock
```

And edit your `php.ini` accordingly:

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

Restart Apache...

```
$ apachectl graceful
```

...and verify that the socket is set correctly:

```
// info.php

phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$mysql = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'mysecret');` to connect via TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

The socket's location should be specified in the mysql .ini file. On debian systems, it should be in `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`. Look for a line starting with 'socket' near the start of the file. Most likely it's set to `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Dae is correct. In a terminal running under an UX OS, type this:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
```

This will give you the address to your sock-file. Compare this to the address in php.ini. If it's something else, then correct it to the address netstat gave you following Dae's advice.

Yes, a remedy is setting the address to 127.0.0.1 but that doesn't really solve your problem.